# Set a COOKIE in Observer and use it in Javascript

Tags: magento-enterprise, javascript, cookie

I have an Observer for customer_login event where I want to set a cookie based on informations from customer session.

```
public function login(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $quote = $customerData->getQuotingEnabled();
    $cookie = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
    $cookie->set('cookiename', 'cookievalue' ,time()+86400,'/');

    return true;
}
```

How it is possible to access that cookie in a javascript file? If I alert(getCookie('cookiename')); it just gives me null. In the Observer the cookie it is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the cookies with javascript like this:

```
var cookies =  document.cookie;
```

But this gives you a string will all the cookies. You need to parse that.

Here is a function that can do that:

```
function getCookie(cname)
{
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Just retrieve your cookie like this:

```
var v = getCookie('cookiename');
```

**[EDIT]**
Not all cookies set through code can be accesses with javascript.  If you pass a parameter (5th I think) when creating a cookie `true` it means the cookie is available only for `http`.

Magento handles this from the config area.
Go to `System->configuraton->Web->Session Cookie Management` and set the value for `Use HTTP Only` to `No`. This should make all cookies (that you set from now on) available in javascript.

---

<sub>Source: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp</sub>

Comment: I already did that..the problem is that the cookie that was set in the observer has no value in javascript.

Comment: @Denisa. see my edit.

Comment: You don't want cookies to be accessable, so only set cookies to be http-NO which you really need in frontend. JS-accessable cookies are a big security issue, because it is easier to get the session id to do EVERYTHING as the user!

Comment: Thank you @Marius :) The setting you suggested was the solution for me and now I can access the cookie.

Comment: Yeah...I showed you how you can make it work because that was the question, but it's not a good idea. as @FabianBlechschmidt says in a comment above setting http only to know opens your website to risk. You probably should rethink your approach on the task.

Comment: What risks are you talking about? That cookie has nothing to do with security issues. Are you saying that that setting will influence other things as well? Because related to my cookie, on which purpose I use it, I don't see any problem.

Comment: Never mind...I end extending FPC...